# Can I use Ubuntu without using the Terminal?

Tags: permissions, gui

I am trying to edit a file, but Ubuntu doesn't let me save the changes. I want to use Ubuntu without being told I need root or administrator permission to do so or being forced to use a Terminal. In other words I want to configure Ubuntu to be more like Windows or Macintosh. This is not insecure; nobody is going to break into my home or hack into my computer.

Surely if this is possible, someone must have written a tutorial on how to make Ubuntu more user friendly.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I would say the Linux permissions model first and foremost protect you against yourself. Performing _everything_  as root is a bad idea.

Comment: If that's so then Windows and Mac would change to become more like ubuntu.

Comment: Actually Windows *is* stepping towards a Linux like user/privilege system. Just think how they added UAC (Userr Access Control) so that now you have to confirm every application that wants Administrator privileges even although you're logged in as admin.

Comment: And Mac is based on Unix, which is like Linux. You have to enter your password to modify system files too.

Comment: I mean no offense. I am trying to make ubuntu easier to use so I can get stuff done. Mac and Windows don't force us to use a terminal or type sudo and I am sure they never will.

Comment: *nobody is going to break into my home or hack into my computer* Possibilities always exist, albeit very small.

Comment: @Kadin easier for whom? For me, it's no problem to use `sudo`, and if I forget, there's always `sudo !!`.

Comment: The proper way to use Ubuntu without terminal is not to use it for anything which doesn't have a graphical user interface, just like you would on Windows. It's entirely possible.

Answer (score 7):

#### File editing

If it's your file that you have created  - power is all yours: you can edit the file as you please. If you belong to the group that owns the file and that group has writing permissions - you can edit it. However, if you're editing something that belongs to a system account - you better think twice.

If it belongs to both root user and root group, use `pkexec` or `gksu` to open text editor, and then edit the file. That uses GUI password verification, unlike `sudo`.

For even more GUI compatability, there is `nautilus-admin` plugin for the file browser to open file as admin directly

[image]

#### Adding yourself to a group and permissions

> This is not insecure; nobody is going to break into my home or hack into my computer.

Um . . .sorry, it is insecure - you're essentially asking here to run everything as administrator. This is the same as having no locks on the door and shouting to the world "Come and steal my stuff - nothing is locked!!!".

Just because *you* don't care, doesn't mean *we* shouldn't care. I don't want another botnet computer out there attacking my server. It's a shared responsibility - hacker might be responsible for attacking my server, but you're also responsible for failing to secure it.

In addition, it is said: *When in Rome do as the Romans do*. Please don't bring the poor habits of Windows design over to Linux world.The way Windows works is not user-friendly. Separation of privilleges model was in place since creation of Unix in 1970s , far longer than Windows existed,and is there for a reason.

Read up this [answer on quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-easier-to-write-viruses-for-Windows-compared-to-OS-X-and-Linux/answer/Sax-zim-Bog?srid=Tv), for more detailed Windows security vs *nix security discussion.

---

#### Addressing some of the comments

> I mean no offense. I am trying to make ubuntu easier to use so I can get stuff done. Mac and Windows don't force us to use a terminal or type sudo and I am sure they never will. – Kadin 10 mins ago

Linux doesn't force you to use terminal. It's just one of the options out there, and the most frequently used one because it's simple and effective. Terminal is just text , no extra noise. There are 'administrator' plug-ins for nautilus , so you can edit files from GUI,so use them.

As for other systems, the terminal *is there, too.* Mac OS X is still a *nix system and also has terminal , so people do use it.  Windows has CMD , it's just that their command line doesn't measure up to the one on *nix, so people don't use it (unless it's a professional system administrator who has to use `PowerShell`). They receive a lot of critique because of that.

> I am trying to change apache2.conf file in etc/apache2 folder. I also want to copy the file and change the name so I have a back-up.

You are trying to alter configuration of Apache. This is admin level task, and should be done only with appropriate privileges. There's no legitimate reason for regular users to have access to this configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am a web developer. I installed LAMP and need access to those files.

Comment: @Kadin it's still an admin level task to edit the configuration files. I would suggest that you add yourself to a group www-data and have those files belong to www-data group as well have them have write permissions.

Comment: @Kadin then just remember to use `sudo`. It's the same thing as using `Run as Administrator` in Windows.

Comment: @Nobody Ask Ubuntu has a strict [be nice](https://askubuntu.com/help/be-nice) policy.  Please make sure you follow it.

Comment: Serg hinted at it, but I want to make sure this is clear. Someone doesn't need to break into your home to wreak havoc on your system. If that computer has internet access and no root protection, one or more of the many bots that troll the web, trying to hack computers will see your gigantic bullseye of a computer. The only way it's secure to take away all security is if you disconnect it from the internet. Even then, it's always possible that someone will break in. It may seem to always happen to someone else, but you are "someone else" to everyone else (Calvin and Hobbes quote there for ya).

Comment: Thanks Zacharee. I think I should have worded my original question as a — "balance of security vs. usability." Obviously there is no such thing as totally secure. 98% of computer users are managing to get by on Windows and Macs without the same security as Linux. I think Linux is designed to use the terminal and I am going to have to learn all the commands and right them down.